# How to make .NET output FIPS compliant pdb debug file?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, pdb-files, fips

I get the following error when I try to build my solution:

> Unable to write to output file ABC.pdb: This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

Points to note:

1. My company works with secure data so I cannot change local security settings to switch off FIPS compliance
2. I cannot change dev.config.exe to make `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false">`

So is there a way to work around this:

1. Is there a way to change a setting such that .NET uses a FIPS compliant cryptographic algorithm to write the .pdb file?
2. Is there any other configuration I can change, or any other way I can build it so that this error does not crop up?

I have searched a lot but found no answers.

Comment: Can you develop on a computer which is not subject to FIPS regulations and then build the solution to be deployed on a computer set to be FIPS-compliant? The cost of an extra computer is likely to be more than made up for by the reduction in development time.

Comment: Which version of the C# compiler and framework are you using? [Looks like there was an issue that was resolved in 4.6.2.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15939)

Comment: Hi Andrew, no I cant develop in another system. I wont be able to take the project from there and deploy it on my computer because of company security policy.

Hi Mike,
I use VB.net and .net version is : 4.6.0, MS Visual Studio 2010 v10.0.3